# Spring load Map value from yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with the following application.yml

```
Detail_1:
  name: X,Y,Z
  place: xplace,yplace,zplace
Detail_2:
  name: X,Y,Z
  place: xplaceanother,yplaceanother,zplaceanother
```

How can I obtain this map in java:

> ```
> X {
> detail1 :xplace
> detail2 :xplaceanother
>  }
> Y {
> detail1:yplace,
> detail2:yplaceanother
> }
> Z{
> detail1:zplace,
> detail2:zplaceanother
> }
> ```

I have tried the following code :

```
@Value${detail1.name}
private String names;
@value${detail2.place}
List<Object> Names = Arrays.asList(getNames().split(",")); 
List<Object> places = Arrays.asList(getPlaces().split(","));
```

Then I tried to create a map of names and places corresponding to detail 1
similarly I fetched names and places for detail 2 
But In this case i end up with 2 maps , one for detail 1 and one for detail 2.
I need to create a single map.

Comment: show the code that you tried

Comment: Can you check my answer? It resolves your issue in 2 different ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation

The following URLs provide good examples in both `.properties` and `.yml` format:

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Please update your config like below in `application.yml`

```
map:
    detail1:
      name:X,Y,Z
      place:xplace,yplace,zplace
    detail2:
      name:X,Y,Z
      place:xplaceanother,yplaceanother,zplaceanother
```

and then configure the property as below,

#### DetailConfig.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="map")
public class DetailConfig {

    private Map<String, Object> detail1;

    private Map<String, Object> detail2;

    public Map<String, Object> getDetail1() {
        return detail1;
    }

    public void setDetail1(Map<String, Object> detail1) {
        this.detail1 = detail1;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getDetail2() {
        return detail2;
    }

    public void setDetail2(Map<String, Object> detail2) {
        this.detail2 = detail2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pojo for property;

```
public class Detail {

    private List<String> name;
    private List<String> place;

    public Map<String, String> getNamePlaceMap() {
        return IntStream.range(0, name.size()).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> name.get(i), i -> place.get(i)));
    }

    // getters/setters
}
```

and use the following configuration to get properties into context;

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "detail-1")
    public Detail detailOne() {
        return new Detail();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "detail-2")
    public Detail detailTwo() {
        return new Detail();
    }
}
```

and autowire them and pass them to the logic where that map is created;

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private Detail detailOne;

    @Autowired
    private Detail detailTwo;

    public void test() {
        System.out.println(createSpecialMap(detailOne, detailTwo));
    }

    private static Map<String, Map<String, String>> createSpecialMap(Detail detailOne, Detail detailTwo) {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        detailOne.getNamePlaceMap().forEach((key, value) -> {
            Map<String, String> subMap = resultMap.getOrDefault(key, new HashMap<>());
            subMap.put("detail1", value);
            resultMap.put(key, subMap);
        });
        detailTwo.getNamePlaceMap().forEach((key, value) -> {
            Map<String, String> subMap = resultMap.getOrDefault(key, new HashMap<>());
            subMap.put("detail2", value);
            resultMap.put(key, subMap);
        });
        return resultMap;
    }
}
```

results in;

```
{
  X={detail1=xplace, detail2=xplaceanother}, 
  Y={detail1=yplace, detail2=yplaceanother}, 
  Z={detail1=zplace, detail2=zplaceanother}
}
```

---

---

Or better in readability, using a `Letter` class;

```
public class Letter {

    private String name;
    private String detail1;
    private String detail2;

    public Letter(String name, String detail1, String detail2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.detail1 = detail1;
        this.detail2 = detail2;
    }

    // getters/setters
}
```

doing the following;

```
private static List<Letter> createList(Detail detailOne, Detail detailTwo) {
    List<Letter> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> detailOneMap = detailOne.getNamePlaceMap();
    Map<String, String> detailTwoMap = detailTwo.getNamePlaceMap();

    Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<>();
    keySet.addAll(detailOneMap.keySet());
    keySet.addAll(detailTwoMap.keySet());

    return keySet.stream()
            .map(key -> new Letter(key, detailOneMap.get(key), detailTwoMap.get(key)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

will result in;

```
[
  Letter{name='X', detail1='xplace', detail2='xplaceanother'}, 
  Letter{name='Y', detail1='yplace', detail2='yplaceanother'}, 
  Letter{name='Z', detail1='zplace', detail2='zplaceanother'}
]
```

which is a better result than a raw map of map...